# Can I get jQuery's load(url) to give me success/error feedback from the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically using a plug-in that makes use of the jQuery `load(url)` function.

Since *.load()* allows you to use a callback function with the response as parameter, I was wondering if there is a way to embed, for example, a variable indicating error or success in the file *.load()* is calling?

In the file that is called you could use something like `$.myPlugin.response = "An error occured"` and the callback function will be able to read it (At least in firefox). The problem however is that `$.myPlugin.response` now is global and if we were to make two *.load()* simultaneously we wouldn't be able to tell which call went bad.

Is there a way to contain this error variable within the callback function or at least in a tighter scope than global?

One way would be to parse the response with regex and look for a specific expression, but that does not feel like the right way to do it.

Could the use of custom headers work out somehow?

I hope the question makes sense

Cheers

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)? Look at the signature for the "complete" callback function.

Comment: Yes I have and I guess you refer to "complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)A callback function that is executed when the request completes." I can't find an explanation for what the two last parameters are there for. A little more help than that would be appreciated.

Comment: `textStatus` is described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (see *"complete(jqXHR, textStatus)"*). `XMLHttpRequest` is the `XMLHttpRequest` object that underlies all axax requests in all browsers (note as of jQuery 1.5 you get a *jqXHR* object instead, which is very similar).

Comment: I guess I somehow have to send these headers from the server side. Which is no problem beside the fact I don't know what headers need to be set. If I instead ask like this: What headers would I need to send to get something to work with from textStatus and XMLHttpRequest. Can I set a custom header that i can ask for in the complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) callback? And how would a header like that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with one of the examples from the [documentation for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<div id="success"></div>
<b>Error Response:</b>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now we'll modify the script deal with a custom error that is returned by the web server or CGI script:

```
<script>
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "custom_error") {
    // the handler for custom_error goes here
  }
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Why do you imply that I haven't read it? How would that example help me? It doesn't say anything about sending custom errors. Just handling a request that did not succeed. Or if it does I obviously haven't understood it since I asked... Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misreading your question... Assuming the web server and page requested is under your control, you can send back whatever errors you need.

<script>
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "your_error") {
    // do something related to your_error
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
  </script>

Comment: Many thanks Mr Muskrat. That is exactly the help I needed. Now I will just try to figure out what header I need to set server side to get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome.I'll edit my response to make it clearer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell jQuery to call a function whenever an Ajax call ends with an error response (see [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText)
    }
});
```

Of course you must return a HttpServerError to achieve this result (how to do this depends on the server-side framework).

E.g. using Django:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError

def myAjaxCall(request):
    """ Return the result if present;
        if not present, return an error with the string "No value to return"
        in case of any other error, return the error with its text.
    """
    try:
        value = compute_my_value(request)
        if not value:
            raise Exception, 'No value to return!'
        return HttpResponse(value, mimetype="application/json")

    except Exception, e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(unicode(e))
```

Comment: The question then: how do I get my backend to mark the response as an error? Call me lazy but I rather get help from someone who knows the answer instead of reading a huge bunch of text. Error is used when the call itself fails. And as I wrote it's not what I need.

Comment: @Roatin Marth - And you are not very helpful.